# Windows Backup failed with I/O error 0x8078002A

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-7-backup

Running Windows 7 SP1 64-bit.

- C = SSD
- D = internal HDD with docs on it.
- E = external HDD partition 1 (2 TB)
- F = external HDD partition 2 (2 TB)

I select Windows can choose which files to back up, and F: as the backup location.

There is enough space on F:

When I run backup, I receive an error:

> Windows Backup failed with I/O error 0x8078002A

Comment: The error doesn't mention anything like _"The backup completed but some files were skipped."_

Answer (score 1):

Found this [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/backup-restore/219909-backup-failed-error-0x8078002a-external-3tb-drive.html):

> Microsoft Image Backup in Windows 7 will not support Seagate 3TB and
>   4TB drives (along with most other external drives above 2.1TB). This
>   article explains.
>
> Microsoft Image Backup in Windows 7 will not support Seagate 3TB and
>   4TB drives (along with most other external drives above 2.1TB).
>
> Microsoft only supports drives that are set up to use 512 byte blocks
>   as destinations for image backups. These drives are compatible with
>   all other Windows functionalities.
>
> To allow 3TB and 4TB drives to work in older operating systems like
>   Windows XP, these drives are configured using 4K byte blocks.
>
> Microsoft has added support for 4K drives in Windows 8. [See here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2510009)
>   for more information.
>
> For more information about the limitations of Windows Backup and
>   Restore, please contact Microsoft.

Comment: Hmm. I'm running Windws 7 64 bit and backing up to a 3TB Seagate drive (1 NTFS format partition) with no problems ... did you run the `setup.exe` that came with the drive?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Okay. It didn't come with a setup, only a Cloud Backup setup program.

Comment: Hmm. My drive had the setup program **on the drive itself** together with `Warranty.pdf` and `Autorun.inf`.